# CMake: IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling a Linux library for ARM using [dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross) and linking to OpenCV. OpenCV builds and installs successfully, but configuring my library gives me errors like this:

```
CMake Error in build/_deps/mylib-src/CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "opencv_core" configuration
  "Release".
```

I'm finding the OpenCV package like this:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

And linking like this:

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I didn't find the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) for IMPORTED_LOCATION very helpful. What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked:

```
set_target_properties(opencv_core PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so)
```

But I still don't know why I needed it...